# Debug=True in Flask not Working

Tags: python, flask

I am new to Flask and am trying to turn on debug so when I type in "http://127.0.0.1:5000/welcome" into my URL it will provide debugging information.
Instead I am given a 404 URL is not found. Which does make sense as I did not create the welcome.html file yet. What is troubling though is it does not provide debugging information. My question is how can I make debug=True work? Even when I do not have the welcome function declared it does not work. 
Currently I have Flask 0.10.1, jinja2 2.8, and Werkzeug 0.11.4.

The terminal prints out:

```
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger pin code: 281-296-874"
```

The following is my code:

```
__author__ = 'Robert'
from flask import Flask, render_template 


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello BBck!"

@app.route("/welcome")
def  welcome():
    return render_template("welcome.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Not quite sure how I fixed it, but after updating Werkzeug, and restarting the computer the debugger is working.

Comment: export FLASK_APP=app.py  # path to app
export FLASK_DEBUG=1
python -m flask run --host=0.0.0.0

If you run it with flask run it doesn't work but it works with python.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your second "@app.route" statement is missing the URL reference
it should read

```
@app.route("/welcome")
def welcome():
     return render_template("welcome.html")
```

Then you might still get a 404 error but that should be because you haven't created the welcome.html file in your templates folder

Comment: Since I have debug=True shouldn't debugging information show up on the webpage? As demonstrated in this link http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#debug-mode

Comment: @Nightlife debug information should appear in the terminal, not in the webpage

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WfpFUmV1d0w (8-9:30) According to this video the point of having debug=True is to receive information on the url?

Comment: @Nightlife Did you change the route as suggested in the answer here? In your question, you have conflicting routes between `hello` and `welcome`. I don't think there are debug pages for 404 and a 404 doesn't happen when TemplateNotFound, that is a 500 error.

Comment: Yes, I get requested url not found. No debugging information.